# Why does this code not work? Python RE (regular expression)

Tags: python, urllib2, expression

I am trying to use RE with python to extract all the products off of a random page. However, I do not know why I am not getting any matches. I am positive that the problem is occurring with the re.findall part of my code, specifically when i add the" .* ".

```
    import urllib2, re
    response=urllib2.urlopen('http:/  /www.tigerdirect.com/applications/Category/guidedSearch.asp?CatId=17&cm_sp=Masthead-_-Computers-_-Spot%2002')
    stuff=response.read()
    laptops= re.findall(r'<div class="product"> .* </div>',stuff)
    for laptop in laptops:
        print laptop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*` is a greedy match, you should probably use `.*?` which is the non-greedy version.

Here is an example of one of the records you are trying to match

```
'<div class="product"><div class="productImage"><a href="../SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=4903661&amp;Sku=T71-156409" class="itemImage" title="Lenovo Z580 15.6&quot; Core i7 500GB HDD Notebook PC"><img src="http://images.highspeedbackbone.net/skuimages/medium/T71-156409_chiclet01xx_er.jpg" alt="It features a powerful 3rd generation Intel Core i7-3520M and a 4GB DDR3 RAM which deliver you a powerful computing performance." onerror="this.src=\'http://images.highspeedbackbone.net/SearchTools/no_image-sm.jpg\'" border="0" /></a></div><div class="productInfo"><h3 class="itemName"><a href="../SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=4903661&amp;Sku=T71-156409" title="Lenovo Z580 15.6&quot; Core i7 500GB HDD Notebook PC">Lenovo Z580 15.6" Core i7 500GB HDD Notebook PC</a></h3></div>'
```

It looks like you need to remove the spaces around `.*` too

```
>>> response=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/Category/guidedSearch.asp?CatId=17&cm_sp=Masthead-_-Computers-_-Spot%2002')
>>> stuff=response.read()
>>> laptops= re.findall(r'<div class="product">.*?</div>',stuff)
>>> len(laptops)
16
```

There are better ways of parsing HTML, such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Thanks!!!! it works. I heard of beautiful soup, but i am not 100% sure I know what it does.

Comment: If that `<div>` has another `<div>` inside of it, the non-greedy version will stop too soon and only capture up to the end of that tag. If you use the greedy version, you'll capture everything between the beginning of the first `<div>` and the end of the last. Regex just won't work here.

Comment: @Blender, you're right. There are numerous questions about the folly of parsing html with regex on SO already. When you get away with it, it's quick and dirty, but there is also that loaded gun pointed at your toes...

Comment: If you guys think that regex wont work here, is there something better?